# How to write different levels of messages into mutiple log files using SLF4J over LOG4j

Tags: java, log4j

I am using SLF4J + LOG4j as per requirement I have to store the logs into multiple log file. When I run the program the logs are written into the log file, but all levels are written but I need unique levels. Can anyone help by providing me a sample code?

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout,debugLog,reportsLog
log4j.logger.debugLog=TRACE,debugLog
log4j.logger.reportsLog=DEBUG,reportsLog


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n


log4j.appender.debugLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.debugLog.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.debugLog.File=C:\\debug.log
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debugLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n




log4j.appender.reportsLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.reportsLog.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.reportsLog.File=C:\\reports.log
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.reportsLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.debugLogger=TRACE, debugLog
log4j.additivity.debugLogger=false

log4j.category.reportsLogger=DEBUG, reportsLog
log4j.additivity.reportsLogger=false
```

Comment: Try to remove the `rootLogger` and check, if it works then.

Comment: if i remove rootLooger logs are not writing to files